# Optimise many-to-many join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: `groups` and `people` and `groups_people` which forms a many-to-many relationship between `groups` and `people`.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE people (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT,
    join_date   TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE groups_people (
    group_id    INT REFERENCES groups(id),
    person_id   INT REFERENCES people(id)
);
```

When I want to query for the latest 10 people who recenlty joined the group which has id = 1:

```
WITH person_ids AS (SELECT person_id FROM groups_people WHERE group_id = 1)
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = ANY(SELECT person_id FROM person_ids)
ORDER BY join_date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The query needs to scan all of the joined people then ordering them before selecting. That would be slow if the group containing too many people.
Is there anyway to work around it?

Comment: Can a person be in more than one group?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because it doesn't handle inline `references` or CTEs.  In the future, tag your questions with the database you are really using.

Comment: @Forklift Yes. A person can be in multiple groups

Comment: @AnyName So wouldn't it make sense to have join_date be a member of group_people?

Comment: @Forklift I made up the example for the question. The meaning of it isn't important. That was a bad example though.

Comment: Then for simplicity, I like @GordonLinoff answer below.

Answer (score 3):

**Schema (re-)design to allow same person joining multiple group**

Since you mentioned that the relationship between `groups` and `people`
is many-to-many, I think you may want to move `join_date` to `groups_people` 
(from `people`) because the same person can join different groups and each
such event has its own `join_date`

So I would change the schema to

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT --,                    -- change
    -- join_date   TIMESTAMP                -- delete
);                                      

CREATE TABLE groups_people (
    group_id    INT REFERENCES groups(id),
    person_id   INT REFERENCES people(id),  -- change
    join_date   TIMESTAMP                   -- add
);
```

**Query**

```
select
    p.id
    , p.name
    , gp.join_date
from
    people          as p
    , groups_people as gp
where
    p.id = gp.person_id 
    and gp.group_id=1 
order by gp.join_date desc
limit 10
```

*Disclaimer*: The above query is in `MySQL` syntax (the question was originally tagged with `MySQL`)

Comment: With this schema, why not just use SELECT TOP 10?

Comment: @Forklift -- My query is in `MySQL` syntax.  (I added a disclaimer to my answer).  Thanks!

Comment: I've just tested the query. If the group 1 contains 1.000.000 people. The query would take approximately 2 seconds

Comment: @Any Name -- Your tables do not have indexes.  You may want to add indexes to speed up lookup operations on the tables.  But this is independent of your original question.

Comment: @leeyuiwah Sorry the my example was a bad one. The join_date column is not appropriate in this case. But you can think about it as register_date or whatever. I've just made it up for the example.

Comment: @leeyuiwah I think adding indexes in this case woundn't help though. The query need to join all people before it can do ordering. The index will probably not work on the joined result.

Comment: @Any Name -- But the observation still applies.  If the same person can have multiple groups, then he or she will have multiple `register_date`, one for each group.

Comment: @leeyuiwah `register_date` I was mentioning is the date which he/she registered the account. BTW, the meaning of it is not important. Again, I apologize for the bad example

Comment: @Any Name -- If that is the case, then the answer by Gordon Linoff should be good enough.  (You still need to add indexes, however, I think)

Answer (score 2):

This seems much easier to write as a simple `join` with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select p.*
from people p join
     groups_people gp
     on p.id = gp.person_id
where gp.group_id = 1
order by gp.join_date desc
limit 10;   -- or fetch first 10 rows only
```

Comment: If the group 1 contains 1.000.000 people. The query would take approximately 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   people p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   groups_people ps
               WHERE  p.id = ps.person_id and group_id = 1)
ORDER  BY join_date DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: it's still slow :(

Comment: If the group 1 contains 1.000.000 people. The query would take approximately 2 seconds.